# How prevent rollbar from reporting errors in the development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

How I can disable the [rollbar gem](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem) from reporting errors in my development environment? I want to get errors only from staging and production, but I didn't find it in docs on Rollbar's site.

Comment: Note that if you disable Rollbar in development with one of the techniques below, then `rake rollbar:test` won't work. You need to enable production mode.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Put this code into initializers/rollbar.rb:

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
  # ...

  unless Rails.env.production?
    config.enabled = false
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: FYI: not actual anymore. https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/generators/rollbar/templates/initializer.rb#L16-L19

Comment: @FilipBartuzi The code you referenced only disables rollbar in test. The question asks to disable it in development.

Comment: I don't have sufficient rights to do this but it would be more clear if the above code sample were edited to reflect the full namespace environment where the code should run.  Recommend to prepend line:  `Rollbar.configure do |config|` and then append the corresponding `end` to the code sample.   Conceivably someone's initializer could be empty or absent and rollbar would still function.

Comment: @LukeGriffiths thansk, added it to answer

Answer (score 13):

I changed the following in config/initializers/rollbar.rb:

```
  # Here we'll disable in 'test':
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.enabled = false
  end
```

to

```
  # Here we'll disable in 'test' and 'development':
  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    config.enabled = false
  end
```

Comment: I'm curious why this isn't the default setup. Who wants dev exceptions sent out?

Answer (score 11):

Don't use an `if` (or `unless`) statement just to set a boolean. Also, you probably want Rollbar enabled in staging in case you need it.

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|

  config.enabled = Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following better answers the question:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  config.enabled = false
end
```

This code should be written in config/initializers/rollbar.rb

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct so I am just adding this to reduce confusion about exactly what code is required:

Ensure the following is in config/initializers/rollbar.rb:

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
  # ...

  unless Rails.env.production?
    config.enabled = false
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I only want Rollbar to report issues in production, so I've done this:

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.enabled = Rails.env.production?
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my rollbar config. 
`config/initializers/rollbar.rb`

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
  # ...

  if Rails.env.in? %w[test development]
    config.enabled = false
  end

  # ...
end
```